# Accentuation des majuscules — Accents on upper-case letters

Tags: orthographe, typographie, diacritiques, majuscules

En français, faut-il accentuer les lettres majuscules ?
Par exemple, doit-on écrire :

> Écriture

ou

> Ecriture

On voit les deux situations très souvent, laquelle doit être utilisée ?

---

Ought accents to be written on top of upper-case letters in French?
For example, which is proper: “Écriture” or “Ecriture”?
Both options are commonly seen, which to choose?

Comment: L'article [majuscule](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majuscule) de Wikipedia, ou un manuel de typographie, couvre bien le sujet. (S'il y a des nuances à faire, poser une question *bien précise*.)

Comment: Le [clavier bépo](http://bepo.fr), en plus d'améliorer la santé de vos doigts, propose tous les signes utiles en français et beaucoup d'autres langues, avec accès facile aux majuscules.

Comment: Voir aussi directement [ici](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-I/academie-accentuation.html#Accentuation) et [là](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1438).

Comment: Despite everything, you may still find unaccented capitals in the most random places. [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCuht.jpg) a shot of my Louis Segond translation of the Bible. « A Dieu ne plaise », says Peter, with little regard for orthographic conventions.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

**Ne pas mettre d'accent sur une majuscule est considéré comme une faute.**

Celle-ci est souvent commise sur les ordinateurs, car mettre des accents sur les majuscules est souvent compliqué et demande un effort supplémentaire. Certaines personnes finissent alors par ne plus en mettre non plus en manuscrit.

Voici la [position de l'Académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#5_strong-em-accentuation-des-majuscules-em-strong) sur ce point :

> On ne peut que déplorer que l’usage des accents sur les majuscules soit flottant. On observe dans les textes manuscrits une tendance certaine à l’omission des accents. En typographie, parfois, certains suppriment tous les accents sur les capitales sous prétexte de modernisme, en fait pour réduire les frais de composition.
>
> Il convient cependant d’observer qu’**en français, l’accent a pleine valeur orthographique**. Son absence ralentit la lecture, fait hésiter sur la prononciation, et peut même induire en erreur. Il en va de même pour le tréma et la cédille.
>
> On veille donc, en bonne typographie, à utiliser systématiquement les capitales accentuées, y compris la préposition À, comme le font bien sûr tous les dictionnaires

---

In English:

**Not putting an accent on a capital is considered an error.**

This is often done by computers because putting accents on capital letters is often complicated and requires extra effort. So some people end up not putting them in the manuscript either.

Here is the [French Academy's position](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#5_strong-em-accentuation-des-majuscules-em-strong) on this issue:

> It is deplorable that accents on capitals are used loosely. One can observe a tendency to omit accents in handwritten texts. In typography, occasionally, some remove all accents on capitals under the pretext of modernism, when in fact it reduces the cost of composition.
>
> It should, however, be noted that **in French, the accent has clear orthographic value**. [The accent's] absence slows reading, definitely slows pronunciation, and can even be misleading. It is the same for the umlaut and the cedilla.
>
> So we shall in good typography, use systematically accented capitals, including the preposition À, as of course do all dictionaries.

Comment: À noter que beaucoup de graphistes/typographes professionnels font cette faute...

Comment: @Brennan Vincent: C'est plus souvent qu'autrement soit pour économiser de l'espace entre les lignes où parce que la police de caractères (le "font") ne contient pas tout les caractères. C'est souvent le cas pour les lettres majuscules, mais ça arrive aussi que d'autres lettres inhabituelle (pour la personne créant la police) tel les ö, les ņ et les þ ne sont pas dans le "registre" de la police.

Comment: J'ai appris quelque chose aujourd'hui. Quand j'ai commencé à étudier le français il y a quarante ans, on m'avait enseigné le contraire.

Comment: En écriture manuscrite, dès qu'on écrit pas dans un style de type "script" à lettres détachées, il fut d'usage de ne pas accentuer la majuscule (on peut se reporter aux textes d'époque 19ème - début 20ème sur le site de la BNF Gallica) , de ne pas ajouter les cédilles, etc. La raison en est graphique, c'est une faute grammaticale pratiquée pour des raisons d'esthétique (taille des lignes, disproportions de la cédille par exemple). Lorsqu'on tape sur l'ordinateur ou une machine à écrire, la grammaire s'applique pleinement.

Comment: Cette règle n'a pas toujours été la même, car en effet, il y a 30 ans, on nous enseignait que mettre un accent sur une majuscule était une faute. Mais il est vrai que désormais on doit les placer, majuscule ou pas.  Une seule exception : les noms propres, si la personne l'écrit sans accent ce n'est, bien sûr, pas une faute. Eric sans accent, prononcé Éric.

Comment: @EricLavoie Le commentaire devrait dire « on m'a enseigné ».  Le "on nous enseignait" est largement exagéré, de par mon expérience personnelle c'est tout le contraire.  Il y a bien plus d'un demi-siècle, les livres dans lesquelles on apprenait à lire avaient des majuscules, j'ai appris à accentuer les majuscules en apprenant à écrire.

Comment: @Yves Avant l'apparition des ordinateurs, on n'accentuait pas les majuscules car les machines à écrire mécaniques ne le permettait pas. Avec les ordinateurs c'est devenu  facile. J'ai appris à accentuer les majuscules à l'école primaire avec l'écriture manuscrite. Je les ai toujours accentuées sauf quand j'utilisais une machine à écrire mécanique car c'était impossible d'y faire les majuscules (sauf à les rajouter à la main une fois le texte tapé.) J'ai appris à accentuer les majuscules dans les textes non manuscrits il y a 30 ans quand je suis passé de la machine à écrire à l'ordinateur.

Comment: En fait, cher M. Eric Lavoie, cette règle n’a pas changé. C’est simplement le Dogme scolaire qui a toujours été dans l’erreur et dans l’absurde.
Pour répondre par la même occasion à M. Brennan Vincent, c’est en vertu des recommandations de l’Académie française, de l’Imprimerie nationale (à laquelle on peut se référée d’après son Lexique typographique) et de l’Office québécois de la langue française, faisant à mon sens d’avantage autorité que l’enseignante de l’école communale, que Louhike a répondu.

Comment: Fauve +1 Par contre, cette règle n'est pas la même dans tous les pays francophones je crois.

Answer (score 20):

J'adhère à la très bonne réponse acceptée. Outre les accents, ne pas oublier les cédilles, les liaisons (Œ) et autres subtilités typographiques.

Pour répondre à Raphink (commentaire ci-dessus), certains typographes faisaient de la résistance. Ainsi Télérama n'a, pendant des années, jamais accentué les majuscules (et cela m'agaçait profondément). Ils ont fini par suivre les recommandations officielles. Je crois que l'Imprimerie Nationale avait décidé d'accentuer les capitales, excepté le A, trouvant le À peu esthétique.

De nombreuses personnes à qui je parle sont opposées aux accents sur les capitales, parce que leur instituteur leur a seriné qu'il n'en fallait pas…
Enfin, c'est vrai que sur un clavier français sous Windows, taper ces caractères n'est pas pratique, même si les correcteurs orthographiques (une fois la bonne option sélectionnée) peuvent aider (sauf dans les cas ambigus mentionnés ci-dessus).

Personnellement, j'avais mémorisé des raccourcis comme Alt+0201 sur le clavier numérique qui me donne un É, mais c'est peu pratique, long à taper… J'ai donc fait un raccourci clavier avec AutoHotkey (d'autres utilitaires peuvent le faire, je suppose), où je tape CapsLock + lettre accentuée pour avoir ces capitales. Dommage que depuis le temps, Windows n'a toujours pas instauré de raccourci simple pour ces lettres courantes (le Macintosh a ces raccourcis depuis longtemps !).

Comment: Windows est un outil américain, ils n'ont pas (ou quasiment pas) d'accent dans leurs mots. J'imagine donc que de faire un raccourcis n'est pas dans leurs priorités. Je pense que ce serait plutôt aux claviers de permettre la saisie de l'accent (comme pour l'accent grave) - ce qui est le cas des claviers portugais (entre autres).

Comment: Le Macintosh aussi est américain. Et les deux ont fait une bonne adaptation au français, faite par des natifs. C'est juste ce problème de clavier qui est ennuyeux.

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez : je ne vais pas passer derrière toi, mais je ne suis pas d'accord avec ta correction de mise en page. Les retour à la ligne sans nouveau paragraphe sont très courants, au moins dans les journaux français. Je préfère indenter la première ligne de ces paragraphes mais à moins d'abuser des nbsp, c'est pas très pratique.

Comment: @PhiLho. Je veux bien en discuter sur méta, mais si le Markdown formatting fait exprès de rendre les retours à la ligne difficiles c'est pas pour rien. Contrairement à un journal, tu ne connais pas la largeur d'affichage, et les retours à la lignes sont souvent très moches quand la taille est proche de celle des phrases.

Comment: @Stéphane : le Markdown est conçu par des américains avec leurs règles propres de typographie. Mais je veux bien admettre que mon style est moins bien adapté à un alignement à droite (non justifié). La largeur de ligne sur StackExchange est fixée, non ?

Comment: À moins que tu ne lises des vers ou un dialogue (et autres cas très particuliers), je ne vois pas où tu as pu voir un texte français qui contient des retours à la lignes sans passer au paragraphe suivant). Pour la taille, je crois que tu rêves un peu vu la diversité des navigateurs, des polices, et des endroits où ces textes apparaissent (listes de questions, twitter, flux rss, version mobile qui est aussi accessible par un lien en bas de la page, etc…). D'ailleurs, le contenu est libre de droits et peut être réutilisé ailleurs.

Comment: À noter pour l'utilisation des accents sous Windows comme sous Macintosh: il existe un outil gratuit pour le faire. http://soft.translator.free.fr/clavier_fr_esp_maj.htm
Téléchargez le fichier et suivez les instructions. J'ai pu l'utiliser sous Windows XP et Windows 8.

Comment: Mauvais système d'exploitation, changer de système d'exploitation?

Comment: Verr Maj ou Fix Maj (le verrou)  + La lettre minuscule sous nombre de Linux

Comment: Il est possible de faire les accents sous Windows comme sur Mac/Linux avec http://soft.translator.free.fr/clavier_fr_esp_maj.htm.

Answer (score 12):

Il faut savoir d'où provient la disparition des majuscules accentuées et autres cédilles en français. Pour autant, cela reste une faute typographique, mais l'origine de cette disparition provient des typographes eux-mêmes.

À l'époque de l'imprimerie au plomb, les accents et les cédilles avaient la fâcheuse tendance à se casser. C'est pourquoi, l'exception, d'une certaine manière, est devenue la règle. Ceci, combiné avec le fait que les systèmes d'exploitation et les claviers n'étaient pas conçus pour facilement taper les É, È, Â, et autres Ç.

Par la suite, les maître-sse-s d'école nous apprenaient aussi qu'il ne fallait PAS accentuer les majuscules. Pourtant, ces cas d'école de typographie signalétique vont vite vous faire comprendre le problème sémantique et de lisibilité :

- CHAMBRE DES DEPUTES → faux, trouble sémantique
  CHAMBRE DES DÉPUTÉS → bon, pas de confusion possible
- PALAIS DES CONGRES  → faux, pas lisible, sémantiquement douteux
  PALAIS DES CONGRÈS  → bon
- MARCHE DE NOEL → une marche de Noël ?
  MARCHÉ DE NOËL → un marché de Noël

Pour taper les caractères accentués ou les cédilles sur Mac OS X ou sur GNU/Linux, il suffit d'enclencher le caps-lock et de taper les touches é, è, ê, ç, etc.

Comment: Sous MS Windows, il est étonnant que rien n'ait été entrepris, mais il existe certainement des utilitaires permettant de réaliser ceci pour les personnes exigeantes.

Comment: [Si vous voulez, le bar est fermé aux congres du fait même que le palais des congres est ouvert au bar](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Desproges).

Comment: @Sebf [How do I type accented characters in windows?](http://superuser.com/q/110605), [Compose key on Windows](http://superuser.com/q/64178). And if you have to use Windows under duress, [How do you configure a Windows machine for a Linux user?](http://superuser.com/questions/282397/282762#282762)

Comment: Le palais des congres est ouvert aux bars ?

Comment: @Yves Pourquoi ne pas mentionner que *congres* et *bars* sont deux poissons de mer. Déjà que le français présente beaucoup de difficultés, ajouter *palais* (de la bouche) et *palais* (bâtiment) nécessite d'expliquer les jeux de mots ; c'est la moindre des politesses que l'on doit à ceux qui s'intéressent à la francophonie.

Comment: Moi je n'ai jamais rencontré de « maître-sse-s d'école » qui m'ont dit de ne pas accentuer les majuscules. Donc cette généralisation est  un raccourci un peu rapide et trompeur. Dommage parce que c'est la seule réponse sur cette page qui a pensé à mentionner les difficultés des imprimeurs avec les caractères en plomb avec les  cédilles et majuscules qui se cassaient. Ce qui est la vrai raison en ce qui concerne l'imprimerie, et pour les tapuscrits l'absence d'accents sur les machines à écrire. L'ère du numérique a changé tout ça.

Comment: Et j'ai déjà vu maintes agences officine d'offres d'emplois qui « RECHERCHE MACON ». J'ai déjà eu envie de rentrer et de leur offrir un carte routière.

Comment: petite remarque presque 5 ans après, mais si j'active le caps lock et utilise la touche "é" de mon clavier belge, ca me donne un "2", le "è" donne "7" et le "ç" donne "9". Quant au "ê" la touche n'existe simplement pas.

Answer (score 9):

Les majuscules doivent être accentuées en français. Dans le cas contraire, la lecture est ralentie.

Un exemple frappant consiste à considérer non pas un accent mais la cédille. Une phrase commençant par le pronom "ça" serait plus difficile à lire si l'on oubliait la cédille.

> Ca va ? Evidemment que ça va.
>
> Ça va ? Évidemment que ça va !

Comment: Dans certains cas, cela peut même conduire à des incertitudes de sens.

Comment: @Raphink : est ce que tu as un exemple avec une ambiguïté ?

Comment: @SylvainPeyronnet Le grand classique est ENFANT LÉGITIMÉ ≠ ENFANT LÉGITIME

Comment: @Gilles: exactement. Le Lexique des règles typographies en usage à l'imprimerie nationale cite également ETUDE DU MODELE ≠ ÉTUDE DU MODELÉ.

Comment: PALAIS DES CONGRES : congrès ou poisson (artificiel, mais a toujours fait rire plein de gens) ? MACONNERIE : oui, les cédilles sont importants aussi ! MARCHE DE NUIT : évènement commercial ou sportif ? (vu sur une affiche...)

Answer (score 5):

Extrait du  ***LEXIQUE DES RÈGLES typographiques EN USAGE À L'IMPRIMERIE NATIONALE***<sup>1</sup> »

Troisième édition (2002), qui est la première édition qui dit dans son avant propos prendre en compte l'arrivée de la PAO.

> L'accentuation fait partie de l'orthographe et l'on devra en PAO, comme pour les autres procédés de composition, s'imposer l'utilisation de codes de types ASCII (*American Standard Code for Information Interchange*) pour « atteindre » à cette accentuation.

À signaler que dans la liste des « Lettres accentuées et diphtongues  » donnée par l'Imprimerie nationale figurent tous les signes diacritiques.

Dans le domaine des signes diacritiques il y a en effet l'avant et l'après numérique. Si les typographes imprimeurs devaient faire face à des difficultés matérielles, cédilles et majuscules qui se cassaient sur les caractères en plomb, comme déjà signalé dans une autre réponse, ou machines à écrire qui n'avaient pas de signes diacritiques, l'arrivée du numérique a changé tout cela et depuis trente ans maintenant nous disposons d'ordinateurs avec lesquels mettre ces signes diacritiques est devenu non seulement possible mais facile car les non spécialistes en informatique trouvent facilement de l'aide sur les nombreux forums et sites spécialisés.

[Suite de l'extrait](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#5_strong-em-accentuation-des-majuscules-em-strong) du blog *Question de langue* de l'Académie Française cité dans la réponse de Louhike :

> On veille donc, en bonne typographie, à utiliser systématiquement les capitales accentuées, y compris la préposition À, comme le font bien sûr tous les dictionnaires, à commencer par le *Dictionnaire de l’Académie française*, ou les grammaires, comme *Le Bon Usage de Grevisse*, mais aussi l’Imprimerie nationale, la Bibliothèque de la Pléiade, etc. Quant aux textes manuscrits ou dactylographiés, il est évident que leurs auteurs, dans un souci de clarté et de correction, auraient tout intérêt à suivre également cette règle.

<sub>1.  Je respecte minuscules et majuscules telles qu'elles sont sur la couverture.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Les accents ont, évidement, pleine valeur orthographique, simplement outre le fait que leur saisie ai été un temps difficile sur les terminaux informatique, un dogme scolaire les interdisait aussi — au mépris des recommandations de l’Académie et du simple bon sens —. J’ai ouïe de nombreux témoignages de personnes rapportant que dans leurs dictés, les enseignants comptabilisaient les majuscules accentuées comme des fautes.
Il faut apprendre à oublier ce que l’École nous a enseigner QPCMFSP.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais vu pratiquer ou eu connaissance de ce « dogme scolaire ». Mes livres de lecture  (il y a bien plus d'un demi-siècle de cela) comportaient des majuscules accentuées. Et je témoigne n'avoir jamais été pénalisé pour avoir accentué mes majuscules quand j'écrivais « à la main ». Il y a toujours eu je pense des enseignants qui connaissaient l’orthographe. Je trouve cette remarque sur l'École (majuscule représentant l'institution, comme dans la réponse) un peu rapide et péremptoire.

Comment: J’ai l’impression qu’il y a un laps de temps durant lequel l’Institution scolaire s’est mise à la mode inexplicable de l’interdiction de diacritiquer les majuscules, au dire des nombreuses personnes qui témoignent ne pas en avoir connaissance et qui ont en commun, soit d’avoir étudié il y a plus de 50ans, soit au contraire d’être sortis récemment de l’école.
Je me demande donc si cette interdiction ne coïncide pas avec la vulgarisation de la machine à écrire que relayera immédiatement après le traitement de texte Word©.

Comment: « Immédiatement après » ? Un siècle d'écart entre la vulgarisation de la machine à écrire et celle de l'ordinateur. Et que vient faire W** ici ? Bien que ce ne soit pas mon outil de travail, je reconnais qu'au moins, comme tous les autres traitements de texte, il a eu l'avantage de permettre la norme qui est de mettre les signes diacritiques. Il n'y a jamais eu d'interdiction de l'Institution scolaire d'omettre les accents (c'est à dire aucune instruction officielle de la part des différents ministères). Il ne peut qu'y avoir eu que des initiatives individuelles de certains enseignants.

Comment: Tous les enseignants que je connu m’interdirent d’accentuer les majuscules. Et, à peut près, toutes mes connaissances du même âge, éparpillées sur plusieurs départements, connurent une telle interdiction aussi.

Concernant la machine à écrire, par « vulgarisation », j’entends le moment où elle s’est massivement introduite dans les foyers et pas seulement le fait qu’elle fut très utilisée dans le milieu professionnel. Compte à son rapport avec Word©, il s’agit de l’impossibilité ou la difficulté d’y diacritiquer les majuscules.

Answer (score 4):

So far, every answer here points in the same direction, that is accentuated letters in French should also be accentuated in upper case, so it is not useful to add my voice to the chorus to state the exact same thing.

So why still make an answer? I just want to point out a location where uppercase letters should almost never be accentuated: the crosswords. It may sound silly, but it could also be a source of confusion if one was to stick with the accents and think they must be part of the crossing words as well. Accents are irrelevent in pretty much all of the French crosswords.

Most people fill their crosswords with uppercase letters, but either way, this would be one case where accents are to be left out, uppercase or lowercase. Crosswords are no litterature, obviously, but they still use writing.

[image]

---

Le jeu de [Scrabble](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lettres_du_Scrabble#Fran%C3%A7ais), ainsi que l’indiqua un temps [cet ami](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/3177) au nom très changeant en commentaire ci-dessous, offre un autre exemple de lettres majuscules non-accentuées (puisque celles-ci ne sont pas disponibles dans le jeu) où l’on peut sans problème faire prendre une valeur accentuée à une lettre, si besoin est, et la lui refuser pour un second mot l’interceptant dans l’autre direction.

De nouveau, il ne s’agit pas ici de production de texte ayant un sens, mais le jeu utilise tout aussi bien la langue écrite pour s’effectuer.

Answer (score 2):

Oui, cela a été dit : il convient d'accentuer ses majuscules en français ! Quelques erreurs se sont en revanche glissées dans les commentaires concernant l'histoire de cette accentuation.
Avant le XVIIIe siècle, il était très difficile aux imprimeurs d'accentuer les majuscules. Cependant, ils faisaient tout pour y parvenir (au moins pour le titre des œuvres).
Les premières éditions des PENSÉES de Pascal (ou de l'Émile de Rousseau), par exemple, reproduisaient bien ces accents.
Tout s'est à nouveau « gâté » au XIXe siècle avec l'apparition de presses rotatives et de machines à écrire d'origine anglophone (donc conçues pour une langue non accentuée)…
Je me permets de vous donner un lien vers mon blog. Je relate en effet cette histoire dans un petit article où je redonne aussi les raisons pour lesquelles il convient vraiment, aujourd'hui (exemples et preuves à l'appui), d'accentuer ses majuscules : [Quand il devient capital d'accentuer ses capitales](http://unmondesansfautes.blogspot.fr/2015/01/quand-il-devient-capital-daccentuer-ses.html)