# Remplacer æ par ae est-il acceptable ?

Tags: typographie, standard, latin, alphabet, ligatures

Pour une certaine valeur d'« acceptable », évidemment.

La ligature *æ* n'est plus employée que pour quelques mots rares, [Wikipédia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/wiki/%C3%86) cite entre autres

> cæcum, nævus, præsidium (forme utilisée concurremment à présidium), tænia (forme utilisée concurremment à ténia), ex æquo, curriculum vitæ et cætera

Compte tenu de la relative difficulté de l'obtenir, en particulier avec un clavier AZERTY sous MS Windows, est-il acceptable de la remplacer par *ae* ? L'Académie a-t-elle donné son avis sur ce sujet ?

Comment: À mon avis la réponse à cette question est la même que celle qui se pose pour [l'accentuation des majuscules](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/60/accentuation-des-majuscules)…

Comment: Le remplacement serait dommage, ne serait-ce que pour _elaeudanla teïtéïa_ de Gainsbourg.

Comment: Il est temps de passer à Linux!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Le *Petit Robert* 1993 donne *cæcum*, *nævus*, *présidium* (variante *præsidium*), *ténia* (variante *tænia*), *ex æquo*, *curriculum vitæ*, et *et cætera* sur un pied d'égalité avec *et cetera*. Il mentionne aussi *cæsium* comme variante de *césium*. Voici la liste des mots qui commencent par `ae` ou une variante diacritique, à l'exclusion de la racine *aéro-* : *aède*, *aèdès* ou *aedes*, *ægagropile* ou *égagropile*, *ægosome* ou *égosome*, *æpyornis* ou *épyornis*, *æschne*, *æthuse* ou *éthuse*, *aétite*.

Le *Trésor de la langue française* donne *cæcum* ou *cœcum* (et signale que l'Académie admettait *cœcum* autrefois, mais plus depuis 1935), *naevus*, *præsidium* ou *présidium*, *ténia* (la graphie *tænia* n'apparaît que dans la section historique), *ex aequo* ou *ex-aequo* (mais pas *æquo*), *curriculum vitae*, *et cætera* ou *et cetera* ou *et cœtera* (la graphie `-œ-` domine dans les exemples). Pour *césium*, aucune autre graphie n'est mentionnée. En initiale, il y a *aède*, *ægagre*, *ægilops* et dérivés, ægipan, aélodicon ou *ælodicon*, *aémère* ou *ahémère*, *æolian*, *æoline*, *æolipyle* ou *éolipyle*, *æolis*, *æpyornis*, *æschne*, *æthéogame* et dérivés, *ætherophon*, *aétite* ou *ætite*, *aevia*.

La plupart de ces mots sont trop peu courants pour que [Google Ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/) donne un résultat intéressant, et en plus le résultat de la numérisation de `æ` est souvent `ae`. On peut voir que pour [césium et caesium (ou cæsium)](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=c%C3%A9sium%2Ccaesium&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3), les deux graphies ont coexisté dès la découverte de l'élément, et que *césium* domine depuis les années 1930 tandis que *caesium* (ou *cæsium*) est moribond depuis les années 1970. Pour [*ténia* et *taenia* (ou *tænia*)](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=t%C3%A9nia%2Ctaenia&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3), la graphie `é` l'emporte aussi aujourd'hui alors que les deux ont longtemps été au coude à coude.

Contrairement à `œ` qui apparait dans des mots courants, `æ` n'apparaît que dans des mots rares, tous dérivés d'un mot latin orthographié `ae`. On peut donc légitimement soutenir que `æ` est une variante de graphie de `ae`, alors que `œ` est une lettre à part entière.

Les caractères `æ` et `Æ` sont présents dans le jeu [latin 1](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1), qui était et est encore le jeu de caractères le plus courant sur les ordinateurs de francophones qui n'utilisent pas [Unicode](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode). Latin 1 n'inclut en revanche pas `œ` et `Œ`, ce qui fait que cette ligature a tendance à disparaître en ligne (et jusqu'au site du TLF !).

Comment: Sur le `œ` un [cahier Gutemberg](http://cahiers.gutenberg.eu.org/cg-bin/article/CG_1996___25_65_0.pdf) donne une anecdote intéressante:  Les lettres françaises œ et Œ n'ont pas été incluses dans ISO/CEI 8859-1 car les principaux représentants francophones dans le groupe de travail n’ont pas estimé cela nécessaire : l'un estimait qu'il s'agissait d'une simple ligature typographique (à tort, soutient l'auteur du cahier), et l’autre était employé par Bull dont les imprimantes ne pouvaient pas les rendre.

Answer (score 4):

Si on part de l'observation que les mots les plus courant ayant un « æ » ont aussi une orthographe alternative avec un « é » à la place de celui-ci, si tu veux éviter la ligature, je te suggère de la remplacer par un « é ». Ça évitera au moins les prononciations incorrectes (« æ » tout comme « œ » se prononce normalement [e] — sauf pour « œ » quand il est suivit d'une voyelle), ce qui était quand même l'objectif d'introduire ces ligatures lexicales.

Answer (score 2):

D'un point de vue purement pratique (et qui ne répond donc qu'à la première moitié de la question, en laissant l'Académie de côté), oui, c'est tout à fait acceptable pour un texte tapé sur un clavier d’ordinateur et non mis en page.

Par exemple :

- Cela serait choquant dans un document de type Word, car les logiciels de traitement de texte sont capables de faire la modification par eux-mêmes: on tape *ex aequo*, ils proposent *ex æquo*. Et plus simplement car on attend des documents issus de traitements de texte un certain respect des règles typographiques.
- Mais cela ne serait absolument pas choquant dans un e-mail en texte brut ou un document au format txt, du fait de l'aspect non standard (au sens bureautique du terme) de ce type de caractères.

Comment: L'aspect "standard" ou non d'un caractère dépend du jeu de caractères utilisé, et non du format de fichier. `æ` fait partie de ISO-8859-1 ; il n'y a aucune raison technique ou pratique de ne pas l'utiliser là où les accents sont utilisés.

Comment: La phrase entière disait "du fait de l'aspect non standard (**au sens bureautique du terme**)" : le commun des mortels utilise les caractères directement accessibles depuis le clavier. Taper ALT-chiffre-chiffre, c'est une démarche d'informaticien.

Comment: Sous Linux KDE, on fait <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> puis <kbd>E<kbd>. Sous Mac OS X, on fait <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. Des systèmes d'exploitation bien conçus répondent au problème. Si les informaticiens veulent utiliser un système d'exploitation plus complexe, c'est leur choix.

Comment: En fait, ce que je voulais expliquer, c'est que tout le monde n'est pas informaticien. La plupart des gens utilisent leur ordinateur comme outil bureautique. Ils ne connaissent pas nécessairement les trucs et astuces de chaque OS. De même pour ce site : il traite de la langue française, pas des astuces de l'informatique. Je maintiens donc ma réponse car elle est basée sur la vraie vie, sur ce que j'ai observé, etc, et non sur des manuels informatiques.

Comment: Ce n'est pas un problème d'informatique, d'accord avec Shlubu. Même sur Linux, pas évident de rendre tous les caractères combinants... comme celui-ci par exemple : ‧̴̵̶̷̸̡̢̧̨̛̖̗̘̙̜̝̞̟̠̣̤̥̦̩̪̫̬̭̮̯̰̱̲̳̹̺̻̼̀́̂̄̃̅̆̇̈̉̊̋̌̍̎̏̐̑̒̓̔̽̾̿̀́͂̓̈́̕̚͠͡ͅ