# Mon curriculum doit-il être vitæ ou vitae?

Tags: latin, alphabet, ligatures

Prise de position de certains protagonistes importants:

- *vitæ*: Le *Multidictionnaire de la langue française*, Wikipedia, wiktionary
- *vitae*: L'Académie, le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/curriculum), [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/curriculum_vitae/21180?q=vitae#21056), [wiktionary](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/curriculum_vitae) (comme « variante orthographique »)

Quel est l'usage dominant? Y a-t-il une tendance historique qui se dégage?

Comment: Tu cherches des informations plus précises que « [Remplacer æ par ae est-il acceptable ?](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1270/remplacer-ae-par-ae-est-il-acceptable) » ?

Comment: @Gilles La réponse la plus complète à la question que tu lies (la tienne!) est générale et plutôt mi-figue mi-raisin: *“On peut donc légitimement soutenir que **æ** est une variante de graphie de **ae**”* — Je cherche des infos spécifiques sur l'usage des deux graphies dans vitæ, et si possible une évolution de l'usage au cours du temps…

Answer (score 4):

D'un point de vue de puriste, æ et œ représentent un seul son, ae et oe deux. On prononce *vité*, donc la première orthographe s'impose. De même "cœur" n'est pas prononcé "co-eur".

L'usage tend cependant à simplifier cela, sauf dans les langues scandinaves, en particulier en français et en anglais, surtout depuis l'ère de la dactylographie puis des claviers informatiques.

Ou bien on simplifie l'orthographe, un æ devenant é, et œ eu, ou bien on admet une incohérence de plus entre orthographe et prononciation, le français et surtout l'anglais ne sont plus à ça près.

Le principe de l'Académie Française a été dès le début "on écrit selon l'étymologie, on prononce selon l'usage" ; principe bien peu respecté, par elle-même, entre cent autres exemples dans "bonhomie".

En anglais, le æ n'est plus guère respecté que par de vénérables institutions, comme l'Encyclopædia Britannica".

Peu écrivent encore "et cætera", tant en français qu'en anglais.

Je suppose que l'on prête plus d'attention au contenu du curriculum qu'à son titre !

Comment: Intéressant… des sources ?

Comment: @F'x Je n'ai rien consulté de précis, n'ai écrit, spontanément, que d'après mon expérience de bilingue lisant souvent des textes assez anciens de français, anglais, ou latin. Il y a probablement de savants articles sur Google, que je laisse aux érudits dont je ne suis pas.

Comment: On peut comprendre que l'*Encyclopædia Britannica* conserve la ligature, ça fait un peu partie de son image de marque !

Comment: @Laure Exact ! Mon "vénérable" était quelque peu tongue-in-cheek.

Answer (score 1):

Je pense qu'il faut préciser de quelle type d'écriture on parle. Il est probable que l'usage de la ligature s'est raréfié avec l'écriture au clavier. Autant faire une ligature quand on écrit au stylo peut être spontané, autant la faire au clavier est beaucoup moins spontané, impossible au clavier de machine à écrire mécanique (français du moins) et difficile au clavier d'ordinateur (ça ralenti la frappe) si on ne dispose pas d'automatismes sur son clavier ce qui est le cas de la majorité des gens.

Ceci dit je viens de faire un ngram et j'ai été surprise que vitae était beaucoup plus fréquent que vitæ, même avant l'apparition de la machine à écrire.

[image: ngram1]

Et encore plus surprise de voir que la ligature æ était au début du 19ème siècle plus fréquente (par rapport au ae non ligaturé) en anglais qu'en français.

[image: ngram2]

Je signale cette question d'EL&U : [*When should I not use a ligature in English typesetting?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50660/when-should-i-not-use-a-ligature-in-english-typesetting) dont deux les réponses sont très intéressantes, et pas seulement pour l'anglais.

Le *Dictionnaire Culturel en langue française* (sld Alain Rey) utilise la ligature *curriculum vitæ* et ne propose pas l'alternative.

Comment: Pour les ngrams, j'ai quand même un doute : le procédé de numérisation/OCR n'introduit-il pas un biais en faveur de la forme *ae* ?

Comment: @F'x: Plus que probable mais dans la mesure où les deux courbes existent on peut imaginer qu'il y ait une tendance ?

Comment: Les occurrence de *vitæ* dans le corpus anglais correspondent pour la plupart à des citations en latin, et pas nécessairement à l'emploi commun de *curriculum vitæ* dans un document qui n'est autrement pas écrit en latin.