# Accents on uppercase letters

Tags: diacritiques

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accentuation des majuscules](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/60/accentuation-des-majuscules)

Is there a consensus in France about showing, or not showing, accents on uppercase letters?  Apart from the circumflex, which seems to be shown as a general rule, I don't see much consistency even where you would expect it, e.g. in road signs showing the names of towns.

I think the accents always appear in dictionaries that show the headwords in uppercase.  But dictionaries are perhaps a special case, since exact spelling is part of their function.

Comment: [This question has already been answered here](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/60/accentuation-des-majuscules?rq=1), albeit in French. If you can't understand it and its answer, we will try to translate them.

Comment: Sorry, I missed it.  I've tried to delete the post but apparently I have to wait a couple of days!

Comment: Don't worry, there is no need to delete it. It is not that it is unrelevant, only that it is a duplicate.