# Ça vs. ca in French

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, étymologie, orthographe, diacritiques

I've started learning French recently, and I've been having a hard time knowing when to use *ça* or *ca* in sentences. What are the differences between these two words and how did they etymologically become different?

Comment: Just want to add that 'ça' is more or less familiar. The right word, not abbreviated, is 'cela'.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

***ca*** is not a word in French. It can only be used as an abbreviation:
 - of [*centiare*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/centiare)
 - of [*circa*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/circa)
and these two abbreviations are rarely used.

Only [*ça*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A7a) exists as a word in French. What you might have encountered is "*Ca*", with a capital 'C'. When typing, some people omit the cedilla on capital 'C', but it is considered as a mistake. This [post about accents on upper-case letters](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/67/358) is also valid for cedillas.

The cedilla modifies the pronunciation of the letter 'c'. *Ça* is pronounced /sa/; without the cedilla it would be pronounced /kɑ/.

A word pronounced /kɑ/ exists in French, it is spelled [*cas*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cas), it is invariable and takes an 's' even in the singular.

Comment: Il y a aussi "ka" (kaon), très utile au scrabble ;-)

Comment: Et il y a aussi « [çà](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A7%C3%A0) », notamment dans l'expression *çà et là*.

Comment: The Ç is not on the french keyboard so we skip it on computers (its a little more practical on smartphone since there is autocorrect)

Comment: By the way if you guys want to type the Ç on a keyboard, hold `alt` and type `0199` then release `alt`.

Comment: @DRz Sorry but this comment is valid only on a PC. On a Mac it's alt+ç. Much simpler.

Comment: I just want to emphasize the fact that **"ca" does not exist** in French. I see it quite often from native French speakers, and frankly, that's ugly.

Answer (score 6):

When people do not have French keyboards available, they sometimes write *ça* as *ca*.  This is becoming much less common as more and more systems are adapted to work with the French alphabet.

The standard spelling is *ça*.  As a learner you should always use *ça* unless you really have no way to type it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have this character on your keyboard, ç, you can almost always write "cela" instead of "ça", although "cela" is more formal than "ça", so you should prefer "ça" in vulgar sentences. The meaning is exactly the same, it's just a matter of style. 
Ça me semble trop cher = Cela me semble trop cher.

Comment: "Ça" is not vulgar, not even informal (which is probably what you meant anyway). Plenty of cases where "cela" would not stand for "ça". And by the way you can type  ç and Ç on any keyboard.

Comment: On a Windows system, if the keyboard layout is set to US, you can type Ç by holding down an Alt key and typing 0199 on the numeric keypad with Num Lock turned on. If the keyboard layout is set to US-International, you must use the left Alt key. (The number keys to press to get ç are 0231.) That said, if you do have the keyboard set to US-International, it's easier to use "dead" keys: just press the key for an apostrophe (') and then type either an upper-case C or a lower-case c.

Comment: So we can replace "Comment ça va ?" by "Comment cela va ?"?

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Technically yes, and I once heard "Comment cela a été", which is similar.