# Accentuation des majuscules pour le nom d'une personne

Tags: noms-propres, diacritiques, majuscules

On a déjà discuté [l'accentuation des majuscules](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/60/accentuation-des-majuscules-accents-on-upper-case-letters?rq=1) ailleurs sur ce site, mais dans les commentaires sur cette question, quelqu'un a suggéré que certaines personnes préfèrent ne pas accentuer la majuscule au début de leur nom (par exemple, Eric au lieu d'Éric).

Est-ce que cette préférence est une décision formelle ou informelle ? C'est-à-dire, est-ce que tous les Eric/Éric sont « Éric » sur l'acte de naissance alors que certains sont « Eric » dans la vie de tous les jours, ou est-ce qu'il y a des actes de naissance qui portent le nom « Eric » et d'autres qui portent le nom « Éric » ?

Si cette différence existe au niveau de l'acte de naissance (et d'autres documents officiels), comment les parents décident-ils d'accentuer ou non le nom de leur enfant ?

Comment: Personnellement, je n'accentue jamais les majuscules, mais uniquement parce que c'est compliqué avec un clavier... Je laisse Word les rajouter... En écrivant à la main par contre, il n'y a aucune difficulté, donc je met l'accent.

Comment: Et moi j'accentue toujours les majuscules, même sur les noms propres et même si les Émile et autres Éric de mes connaissances n'en mettent pas (c'est leur problème, non ?) Ça je le fais bien sûr même au clavier. @Random Difficile ? Ah bon.  Faut se servir des deux mains c'est tout. Les actes de naissances à mon avis ça dépend de si l'employé de mairie sait faire des majuscules accentuées sur son clavier.

Comment: L'État Civil semble exiger l'utilisation des majuscules accentuées (voir http://lalutotale.com/2016/01/09/etat-civil-a-31-ans-je-decouvre-que-mon-identite-est-erronee/ ), mais rien n'est simple avec l'Administration (http://accentuez.mon.nom.free.fr/Dossier-PropositionDeLoi.php )

Comment: Je me souviens d'un article du Canard Enchaîné racontant que le Premier Ministre Edouard Balladur avait exigé du Journal Officiel qu'ils arrêtent d'accentuer son prénom, et le Canard avait par la suite orthographié son prénom "Euhdouard".

Comment: @Random, Laure, SteffX: Pour les discussions sur comment taper des accents sur un ordinateur, merci d'aller sur le [salon de clavardage](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/chez-cosette).

Comment: Il est intéressant de noter qu'indépendamment du choix de la personne ou des parents, les accents ne figurent pas sur les cartes d'identité française où les noms sont écrits en majuscules. Étrange, dans ce cas, que l'État Civil exige les majuscules accentuées si j'en crois le commentaire de SteffX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selon la loi québecoises (et probablement canadienne), un parent peut donner presque n'importe quel prénom à son enfant. Cela inclus aussi l’orthographe.

Pour revenir à la question:

#### C'est une question de choix

Comme qu'il est possible d'écrire Éric, Érick ou Eric, chacun de ces noms est valide.
Sur l'acte de naissance et le registre public, l’orthographe est la même.

#### Il y a toujours des exceptions

Un parent voulant être spécial pourrait être tenté de faire un monstre tel que « Ðåɳḭȼҟ ». Dans un cas comme celui-ci seulement les caractères utilisés dans un français (ou anglais) courant peuvent être utilisés. Le nom officiel sur le registre serait « Danick ».

#### Ce n'est pas pareil partout

En France, la possibilité d'écrire presque n'importe quel nom ne date que de 1993. Au Danemark, les parents doivent encore choisir le nom dans un registre pré-approuvé qui inclus les accents.

#### Donc?

Si le prénom est écrit avec un accent, le nom en prend officiellement un sinon il n'en prend pas. Le choix revient aux parents. Suite à cela l'application de son accent revient à celui qui l'écrit au quotidien.

---

Ceci ce base sur la loi dans mon petit coin du monde et comme mentionné n'est pas identique partout. Puis personnellement, si j'avais une première lettre accentuée je serais probablement moins dérangé qu'elle le soit ou non que de me faire changer mon 'i' par un 'y'

Answer (score 2):

En France il n'y a pas de législation quand à l'orthographe des noms qu'on peut donner à son enfant. Certes, certains noms peuvent être l'objet d'oppositions mais pas pour une question d'orthographe.

Ainsi des parents peuvent tout à fait choisir d'appeller leur fils Eric, ou Éric, ou même Êrrïque si ça les amuse. C'est le nom choisi qui sera marqué sur l'acte de naissance. Par la suite il est possible que certains demandent à être appellé différemment, et/ou qu'ils fassent une démarche pour faire changer leur nom officiellement.

Pour les noms qui proviennent des saints du calendrier, en général on reprend l'orthographe de celui-ci, donc des parents soucieux de normalité ne nommeront pas leur fils Eric (sans accent). Pour les autres noms il n'y a pas vraiment de référence.

Comment: Bleh.. J'écris trop lentement. Ça m'a pris 1 heure écrire mon post pour donner l'impression que j'ai recopié du tient.

Comment: Ton post est très bien, ne t'en fais pas ! Mine de rien on ne donne pas les mêmes infos.