# Pronouncing "é" in initialism

Tags: prononciation, acronymes

When one pronounces the <strike>acronym</strike> initialism (thanks @Laure) ENS (for École Normale Supérieure), does one pronounce the E

- as /ə/ (like the French letter "e"),
- or as /e/ (like the sound "é" usually makes)?

And does this rule generalize to other initialisms involving letters with accents?

Comment: Strictly speaking ENS (/ə.ɛn.ɛs/) is an [initialism](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/initialism).  Is your question about how to pronounce E in initialisms or acronyms? Different rules might apply for each. [ESPÉ](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89cole_sup%C3%A9rieure_du_professorat_et_de_l%27%C3%A9ducation) is an acronym /ɛs.pɛ/ where both letters *e* are pronounced as in the source word. In acronyms it is usually the case ([EHPAD](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tablissement_d%27h%C3%A9bergement_pour_personnes_%C3%A2g%C3%A9es_d%C3%A9pendantes)). Initialism RER is /ə/.

Comment: I don't teach French but é is pronounced like that in whatever position. By the way, you would say é in an initial position [in a word].  Normally, one does not pronounce the acronym for that school. One says in spoken language: Normal Sup. No one goes around actually saying: l'ENS. ENS is used in ***written texts only***.  Ergo the issue is moot. They either say the whole thing or Normal Sup, not l'ENS. But if you did, you would pronounce the é that is not put in the caps in French.

Comment: @Lambie I agree ENS is rarely used but they are many alternative examples where the norm is to pronounce the letters individually like HEC (*Hautes **É**tudes Commerciales*) or EDF [***É**lectricité de France*).

Comment: It's not unusual for "E" in an initialism to be pronounced /e/ in Belgium, especially if it's the last letter, but that's unrelated to the orthography, or the pronoucition of the word that supplied the initial (OCDE /ɔ.se.de.e/ E is /e/ in the base word -économie-, ONE /ɔ.e.ne/, PME /pe.e.me/, E is /ɑ̃/ in the base word -enfance and entreprise-.

Comment: People actually say: Il travaille à l'O-C-D-E, the é is not pronounced. And they don't say: Il a fait l'É-N-S. It's pronounced like a regular E in French. E-N-S. Also, in English, we don't say initialism. We say an e in initial position. Also, ***il a fait l'H-E-C*** [for pronunciation], also without the é sound. Just regular e in French. The e is said, but the é is not heard even if the word has an é.

Comment: @Lambie Even while they are a minority, some people do pronounce these E's as /e/. Initialism is a specialized linguistics term that definitely [exists in English](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/initialism). See also [urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=initialism) ;-) *Il a fait l'H.E.C* (with an article) is not the idiomatic way people say it. That is *Il a fait H.E.C*. If you really want to use an article, that should be plural *Il a fait les H.E.C.* but I doubt anyone really says it that way.

Comment: @jlliagre Initialism is the wrong word to use here.  Anyway, never mind that. Et moi, ayant fait l'ESIT, je reconnais que lá tu as raison. L'ESIT, dit d'un coup, se prête à la prononciation de l'é. Tout comme l'ENA. Par contre, en disant HEC, on ne dit pas: H-É-C, pas vrai? Et puis, je me suis trompée, n'ayant pas fait HEC sans article. Mais en tout cas, il me semble que pour une école, on est obligé de prononcé le é quand c'est faisable. Pour  ENS...on dit plutôt Normal Sup, n'est-ce pas? Pour éviter le fait que ENS ne fait pas un "mot": l'ésit ou l'éna, pas vrai?

Comment: @Lambie Tu confonds les sigles (comme HEC, EDF, OCDE, ENS) et les acronymes (comme ESIT, ENA, ONU). Les premiers sont **sont** des *initialisms*, c'est à dire des suites de lettres épelées, les seconds sont des mots prononcés normalement.

Comment: Non, ils sont tous des sigles. Que l'on prononce comme un mot ou pas. Laissons de côté la distinction sigle (acronym) et initailism pour l'instant. Ce que je disais c'est que la seule différence oralement vient du fait que l'on peut effectivement prononcer les seconds comme mots étant donné la phonologie du français, syllabisatiion, si tu veux. Il est impossible de prononcer HEC, EDF, OCDE, ENS comme un mot. Pas vrai?

Comment: @Lambie Pas forcément. Bien qu'on ne le fasse pas, il est techniquement possible de prononcer HEC comme on prononce « nec » dans *nec plus ultra*. C'est d'ailleurs ce que font parfois certains étudiants étrangers qui disent *heck* quand ne connaissent pas la prononciation standard. En France, certains prononçaient URSS comme [yʁs] au lieu de séparer les lettres. Il y a aussi parfois [ʁɛʁ] pour RER. A l'inverse, on ne prononce pas SPA, CE ou FO comme si c'était des mots alors que c'est bien sûr techniquement possible.

Comment: @jlliagre Cher ami, lá tu y vas un feu fort....:), je parlais des usages courants pas de trucs quasi "hors champ". Pour l'URSS, oui, mais franchement HEC comme nec, fait rigoler un peu. Il a fait HEC...on dirait une interjection....Je sais comment on prononce ces trucs, j'y ai vécu 16 ans...J'essaie de faire une espèce de régle pratique pour expliquer pourquoi. Il faut songer à la sonorité et phonologie. J'y réfléchirai..

Comment: @Lambie Je suis bien sûr d'accord à propos des usages courants. Une abréviation composée d'une suite de lettres indépendantes est souvent prononcée comme un mot quand c'est possible et dans les autre cas, les lettres sont épelées. Je répondais juste à l'affirmation « Il est impossible de prononcer HEC comme un mot », alors que « nec », « bec », « sec », « mec » et « hep » démontrent clairement l'inverse. Le fait que personne ne prononce HEC ainsi n'est donc pas dû à une impossibilité phonologique. Quant à la sonorité, on dit bien « il a fait X », ce qui n'est pas très éloigné, ~ 6 km ;-)

Comment: Personne ne dit: J'ai fait HEC. [comme nec]. Cela ne fait pas parti des usages, voyons. Je suis d'accord avec toi, "quand c'est possible" et je pense qu''il y a une logique phonologique en jeu. Ces  possibilités de prononciation cachent une "règle" pas encore élucidée....

Comment: @Lambie S'il y a une règle à trouver, elle tient sûrement beaucoup à la longueur des abréviations. On a plus tendance épeler les sigles courts prononçables que les longs. Probablement toujours ceux de deux lettres, plus rarement ceux de trois lettres: CAF, CAC, INA, LEP, MIN, PAC, REP, RIB ne s'épèlent pas alors CIC, OPA, RER, SAV si. Pour ONU, les deux s'entendent. Les abréviations de quatre lettres et plus sont le plus souvent prononcées comme des mots (si c'est techniquement possible bien sûr).

Answer (score 2):

Accents on capital letters must be written, they have a full orthographic status so writing *Ecole*, albeit frequent, is a mistake. See [Accentuation des majuscules — Accents on upper-case letters](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/60/accentuation-des-majuscules-accents-on-upper-case-letters/8475#8475)

However, the rule is [relaxed](https://www.uottawa.ca/services-linguistiques/guide-de-redaction/regle-d-ecriture/accent-sigles-acronymes) with most acronyms (or more precisely initialisms<sup>1</sup>) with which accents are often traditionally omitted like with [ENS](http://www.ens.fr/) and [HEC](http://www.hec.fr/).

See also: http://www.hec.ca/qualitecomm/chroniques/franstan/sigleaccentues.html

If the accent is not there, the pronunciation normally follows the rule so these initialisms are  pronounced as "*euh enn ess*" /ə.ɛn.ɛs/ or "*hache euh cé*" /aʃ.ə.se/.

There are nevertheless some people that write the accent "*ÉNS*" and more rarely "*HÉC*" and thus pronounce "*é enn ess*" /e.ɛn.ɛs/ and "*hache é cé*" /aʃ.e.se/.

That said, ENS is often "pronounced" *Ulm* or *Normale Sup'*…

<sup>1 Thanks @laure for bringing that word to our knowledge</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, the pronunciation exactly follows the orthography (specifically the inclusion/exclusion of the accent aigu), and the only ambiguity is whether one chooses to include the accent or not, for which one way may be more common than the other (e.g. your comment about HÉC being rarer than HEC). Would that be a fair summary of the situation?

Comment: Oui, la rue d'Ulm oú cela se trouve, Normal Sup. Juste une chose: ne pas écrire É avec l'accent ne veut pas dire que ce n'est pas prononcé comme é. Voilà la confusion.....

Comment: It should always follows the orthography when an accented acronym is read but otherwise, personal preferences plays a role too. For example, some people say /e.de.ɛf/ instead of /ə.de.ɛf/ while reading EDF. They are of course understood.

Comment: Il y a plusieurs ENS : ENS Paris, ou ENS Ulm, situé rue d'ULM à Paris ; ENS Lyon, à Lyon ; ENS Cachan, à Cachan (et bientôt sur le plateau de Saclay en 2018, plus précisément à Gif-sur-Yvette sauf erreur). Bien entendu, Ulm est la plus connue, et pour certaines personnes qui ne sont pas "du milieu", dire "ENS" ou "Ulm" est équivalent. Mais on peut distinguer, en disant par exemples "les ENS", pour les désigner toutes les trois, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First we can point that in French with capital letters, the accent is not compulsory, therefore `École` = `Ecole`; the word would still pronounce the same.

I don't think there is a real strict agreement for acronyms (or initialisms) and you are free to use them as you wish but for moderation the general rules are:

- we always use capital letters
- we never retain the accents

Any large instance/company will follow as much as possible these rules.

For the pronunciation it is the same, there isn't a real strict agreement but we pronounce the letters as they are written. the motivation is that acronyms are not meant to be used for representing each word but to give a shorter name to a fixed redundant set of words.

therefore ENS (for École Normale Supérieure), will pronounce as /ə/ (the French letter "e")

This said if you pronounce /e/ or even write `ÉNS` it is not incorrect, but those who already use the acronym for a long time may feel uncomfortable. Also those attached to rules may bring the ones I described above.

Comment: This is a personal opinion and you are entitled to it, but answers should say when opinions vary. Even the Académie Française says capital letters should be accentuated. ENS is not an acronym although the rest of your an answer only deals with acronyms (check [here](https://www.druide.com/fr/enquetes/pour-les-cingl%C3%A9s-des-sigles-et-les-accros-des-acronymes) for the difference).  Then you say "for acronyms ... we always use capital letters": a lot of people will say when the acronym has become a new word it can be accentuated (espé, cédex...).

Comment: é in initial position in acronyms is not accented in writing and is not pronounced when spoken. Accented and not accented. Not accentuated which means something different. Capital letters may be accented but é in acronyms are  not. HEC=Haute École Commerciale. Not in the acronym and the é sound of the word not pronounced in the acronym.