# Est-il préférable d'écrire n'importe quel prénom avec l'initiale « E » sans accent ?

Tags: orthographe, diacritiques, prénoms

Je sais qu'il y a des prénoms avec l'initiale « E » sans accent.

Par exemple, j'ai vu les prénoms non pas « Éthan » mais « Ethan », non « Élise » mais « Elise », non « Éléna » mais « Eléna », etc.

D'après ce site https://www.naissance.fr/prenoms/top50/2017, les prénoms avec l'initiale « E » ont les différentes orthographes.

- Les prénoms filles : **É**lise, **E**den, **É**léna, **E**va, **E**my, **É**lina, **É**loïse, **E**léa, **É**léonore, **É**line, **É**lisa...
- Les prénoms garçons : **E**than, **E**liott, **É**van, **E**lio, **E**lias...

Wikipédia insère aussi les articles qui s'intitulent « **É**lise », « **É**lisabeth » et « **E**van » à la fois.

En plus, pour autant que je recherche, il y a des gens ne préfèrent ni « Éléna » ni « Eléna », mais « El**e**na ». « Est**é**ban » non plus : Ils l'écrivent sans aucun accent. Ils expliquent ces orthographes par leur simplicité et les origines étrangères des prénoms.

Alors,

- Préférez-vous personnellement d'unifier ces orthographes, ou pensez-vous que c'est aussi bon même si ça dépend de chaque prénom et de son origine ?
- Comment écrivez-vous les prénoms au-dessus ?

Comment: *Je sais bien qu'il est à souhaiter qu'on écrive les majuscules sans accent*...  Ça commence mal : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/60/accentuation-des-majuscules-accents-on-upper-case-letters

Comment: Merci pour votre remarque. J'ai corrigé la phrase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L'accentuation et plus généralement l'orthographe des prénoms est libre, ce sont des noms propres.

L'administration française considère qu'une différence d'accent invalide le lien entre des actes d'état-civil incohérents. Il est donc fortement recommandé de se tenir à l'orthographe des prénoms telle que définie dans l'acte de naissance des individus pour tous les documents officiels.

Pour ce qui est du choix, je préfère mettre des accents là où ils se justifient facilement, par exemple ***Églantine, Élise***.

Pour les prénoms étrangers, tout dépend de l'intention.

Soit on souhaite garder l'orthographe originale souvent sans accent, ce qui a un sens, mais est parfois impossible (accents toniques ou n tilde n'existant pas en français par exemple: **Ángel**), soit on souhaite franciser le prénom ou il l'est déjà, et dans ce cas, l'accent est à mon avis préférable.

Rien n'oblige cependant à le mettre.

Comment: Merci beaucoup. Donc vous préférez, si sans aucune intention, ces orthographes : Élise, Éden, Éléna, Éva, Émy, Élina, Éloïse, Éléa, Éléonore, Éline, Élisa, Éthan, Éliott, Évan, Élio et Élias ?

Comment: Élise, Éden/Eden, Éléna/Elena, Éva/Eva, Émy?/Emmy, Élina, Éloïse/Héloïse, Éléa, Éléonore, Éline, Élisa, Ethan, Eliott, Évan/Evan, Élio/Elio et Élias

Comment: J'y suis. Votre réponse m'a servi de leçon. Merci :)

Answer (score -3):

Bonsoir
Ma fille s appelle Eve, pour la simple et bonne raison que jusqu en 2018 on ne mettait pas d accent sur les majuscules et qu un prénom n est pas censé s écrire en cursive. Pour ma part Ève ou Éva ne me semble pas du tout logique comme orthographe même si ce ne st pas erroné en langue française. L 'accent peut permettre de conserver la prononciation française car sans celui ci en anglais elle s appelle " Ive". Tout un sujet donc cette histoire d accent!
Bonne soirée

Comment: L'état civil impose que tous les actes soient rédigés en français et a toujours autorisé les accents sur les majuscules et les minuscules. Le fait que des cursives soient utilisées ou pas n'a pas d'importance. Ce qui pose problème, ce sont les prénoms contenant des accents qui n'existent pas en français comme l'accent aigu sur le i (**í**) ou le n-tilde (**ñ**).

Comment: "Un prénom n'est pas censé s'écrire en cursive" D'où vient cette règle / ce raisonnement ?