# Les noms qui sont des prénoms

Tags: prépositions, noms, morphologie, prénoms

Certains noms de famille français sont indiscernables de prénoms: par exemple, *Édouard Philippe* et *Philippe Édouard*. Le phénomène existe aussi en [anglais et allemand](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/71576/41178), mais il me semble être particulièrement répandu en français (expériences personnelles, mais aussi des [blagues typiquement françaises](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wsGGh5Mo2A).)

En outre, il y a beaucoup de langues qui ont des indicateurs pour les noms de familles, qui littéralement signifient *fils de* et lèvent toute ambiguïté:

- les suffixes *-ov / -ić / -skii* en langues slaves, *-son / -sohn / -dottir* dans certains des langues germaniques, *-oglu* en turque.
- les prépositions comme *ben / bin / ibn* dans les langues sémitiques (*Osama bin Laden*, *Solomon ben David*)

Y-a-t-il des raisons particulières pour lesquelles aucun système de ce type n'existe en français ? Est-ce que les constructions comme *Édouard de Philippe* sont limitées aux aristocrates ou y-a-t-il des différences régionales?

Comment: Il est écrit en anglais mais cela pourrait vous intéresser : https://ancestralfindings.com/what-you-need-to-know-about-french-surnames/

Comment: @DerekAllums ça dit que en français aussi les noms derivés de prenoms pourraient être marqués soit par *de*, soit par un suffix (mais sans des exemples, malheuresement). Ma question est par consequence principalement concerne pourquoi il y a tant de noms sans aucun marqueur.

Comment: Elle est une question très intéressante mais je me demande si elle ne serait pas mieux posée sur linguistics.stackexchange ou history.stackexchange.

Comment: @DerekAllums Indeed, let's see what comes out of it: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/45125/27599

Comment: Intéressant, mais "nom prénoms" proviennent-ils bien de la filiation ou bien y-a-t-il autre chose ?

Comment: @XouDo c'est une bonne question aussi. Selon le lien partagé ci-dessus par DerekAllums, les noms provenants de la filiation ont paru même avant tous les autres noms.

Comment: Il n'y a pas vraiment beaucoup de blagues "typiquement françaises" sur le sujet. La vidéo est parodique. *Prolifération of jokes* est très exagéré. PS: Tu as écrit *Eduard* au lieu d'*Édouard* sur LNG.

Comment: @jlliagre je suis d'accord que le *prolifération* est exagéré. Je l'ai mentionné pour indiquer qu'il s'agit d'un phénomène reconnu comme assez commun par les français (alors que en anglais ça serait plutôt une rarité, à mon avis). [Ici est une autre](https://www.legorafi.fr/2022/09/05/horoscope-du-5-septembre-2022/): *Balance : Méfiez-vous des gens dont le nom de famille est un prénom. Attaquez-les si nécessaire.* (En admettant qu'aucune de ces blagues n'est pas basée sur la confusion entre le nom et le prenom, mais sur la prépondérance du phénomène.)

Comment: Il y a deux chose différentes: 1. Des noms de familles qui sont aussi des prénoms, et 2. Des blagues à ce sujet. Le 1. ne fait pas de doute, et c'est encore plus vrai si on ajoute les prénoms avec diminutifs, le 2. n'est pas significatif pour moi. Il y a probablement plus de blagues sur les patronymes qui sont des métiers ou des particularités physiques que des blagues sur les noms qui sont des prénoms.

Comment: PS: Ce serait bien que tu n'écorches pas le (pré)nom **Édouard** sur les sites linguistics et German language. Je peux faire ces corrections sur FSE mais je n'ai pas les privilèges pour le faire partout.

Comment: @jlliagreidéalement j'aimerais voir des données statistiques sur la partie de nom-prenoms dans des langues différentes. Les blagues sont, à mon avis, l'evidence demi-anecdotique: leur existence signifie que le phénomène est largement reconnu par les français. Il y a peut-être quelques noms comme ça en anglais, mais c'est trop rare pour faire des blagues.

Comment: C'est mieux mais il manque le *O* d'*Éd**o**uard*

Comment: @jlliagre une autre question potentielle : pourquoi certains prenoms permettent les versions avec ou sans accente. Exemple: *Éva* vs. *Eva*.

Comment: Bien que restreinte à l'alphabet et diacritiques français, l'orthographe des prénoms est libre en France. On peut nommer sa fille **Eva**, **Éva**, **Evva**, **Aeva**, **Æva**, **Êvah**, etc. Comme **Eva** est un prénom étranger (en français, c'est **Ève**), l'absence d'accent peut facilement se justifier, mais comme je l'ai dit, il n'est pas nécessaire de le faire. Les seuls prénoms interdits sont ceux qui peuvent porter préjudice à l'enfant, ce qui est parfois subjectif. J'ai d'ailleurs déjà répondu à [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/28411).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il n'existe pas en français de préfixe ou suffixe dédié à l'indication d'une filiation pour un patronyme.

Le préfixe *de* est à peu près toujours associé à un lieu (Dubois, Delamare, Dubosc, Dupré), éventuellement lié à une possession nobiliaire (de Musset, de La Fontaine, de Sévigné, de La Fayette), beaucoup plus rarement à un prénom (Dejean ou Depaul).

On soupçonne en revanche que beaucoup des diminutifs de prénoms pourraient indiquer cette origine :

> *En fait, le français utilise surtout une infinité de suffixes diminutifs, variables selon les régions, mais rien ne nous permet d'affirmer qu'ils marquent chaque fois la filiation. Voici quelques exemples, à partir du nom Pierre. J'indique pour chaque suffixe le département où il semble être le plus répandu : - ain : Perrain (17) - ard : Pierrard (08), Perrard (88), Perreard (74) - aud : Perraud (44) - auld : Perrauld (85) - ault : Perrault (49) - aut : Pierraut (57) - aux : Perraux (35) - eau : Perreau (58) - eaud : Perreaud (69) - eault : Perreault (71) - eaux : Perreaux (21) - el : Perrel (43) - et : Perret (01) - ic : Perric, Peric (56) - in : Perrin (88) - od : Perrod (39) - on : Perron (56), Pierron (88) - ot : Perrot (29), Pierrot (88) - oud : Perroud (38)*
>
> *À cette liste non exhaustive, il faut ajouter les doubles diminutifs, tels que Perrineau, Perrinet, Perronnet, Perronneau, Perrenot (Pernot), Perrenaud, Perrenoud, Perrichon, Perrichet, Pierrinat, Pierrotet etc...*
>
> *Ajoutons également les noms formés par aphérèse (suppression du début du mot) et viennent s'ajouter d'innombrables possibilités. Par exemple, avec Nicolas : Colas, Collas, Colet, Collet, Colin, Collin, Collard, Collardot, Collaud, Collaudin etc...*
>
> Jean Tosti, [Généawiki](https://fr.geneawiki.com/index.php/Les_marques_de_filiation)

Si on inclut les patronymes originaires de régions aujourd'hui françaises mais non françaises/francophones au moment de la création des patronymes, on peut trouver des préfixes ou des suffixes marquant la filiation:

> Diminutifs bretons, marques de filiation
>
> Pour marquer la filiation ou donner au nom une valeur affective, la Bretagne dispose de nombreux suffixes qui lui sont propres. C’est le cas en particulier de -ec et surtout -ic, à l’origine de tant de patronymes : Robic (diminutif de Robert), Péric, Perrec, Alanic, Jouanic. Très répandu également, le suffixe -ou, que l’on trouve dans Daniélou, Jannou, Evenou. Dans la région de Vannes, ce suffixe devient -o et donne des noms comme Oliviero, Oliero, Paulo, Pédrono, Perrodo. Egalement très bretons sont les suffixes -an et -en , moins spécifiquement breton mais fort répandu aussi le suffixe -in. Notons enfin des doubles diminutifs en -egan, -eguen. [...]
> Mais la Bretagne possède, et c’est peut-être sa principale originalité, un préfixe de filiation d’origine celtique. Ecrit au départ mab-, il est en effet l’équivalent de l’irlandais et écossais mac-, et est devenu par la suite ab-. C’est ainsi qu’Aballain signifie le fils d’Alain et Abhervé le fils d’Hervé. Parmi les autres noms commençant par ab-, on notera en particulier Abgrall, Abguéguen, Abhamon, Abjean (également Mabjean), Appriou (formé sur Riou). Cette liste montre que la préfixation en ab-, surtout pratiquée en Léon, s’est appliquée à des noms d’origines diverses, et pas seulement à des noms celtiques.

Source: [Les noms de famille bretons, Généanet](https://www.geneanet.org/explore/surname-origins/post/les-noms-familles-bretons/).

En Corse, la formation des noms est identique à ce qu'on rencontre en Italie, donc les enfants de Pierre (Pietro) se sont appelés Pietri (Les Pierre), de Lucien (Luciano), Luciani (Les Lucien), de Paul (Paolo), Paoli, Toussaint (Santo), Santoni, Matthieu (Matteo), Mattei, Albert (Alberto), Albertini, etc.

Comment: Je rajouterais tout de même les patronymes relatifs au physique ou au caractère: lejeune, petit, legras, lebon, vaillant, etc., ainsi que ceux relatifs aux métiers: lemetayer, marchand, fournier, boulanger, etc.

Comment: @Necklondon Pourquoi les rajouter ? Ce ne sont pas des prénoms.

Comment: Vous avez raison je dois être fatigué ce soir, j'ai lu de travers. Au temps pour moi...