# What's the difference between étude and etude?

Tags: orthographe

When I'm typing a Google Doc, it thinks I misspelled "étude" and wants to replace it with "etude." But my French teacher says it is "étude." Note: I'm looking for the noun for study hall, not the verb.

Comment: `etude` doesn't exist, you have to add accent, the right form is `étude`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no etude/Etude in French. The correct form is étude/Étude. See

https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%A9tude/31591/difficulte

http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9tude

There is a high chance to encounter **Etude** nevertheless. 
The reason is that many people omit to put accents on capital letters.
So they write Ecole Polytechnique instead of École Polytechnique.
[Académie Française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#5_strong-em-accentuation-des-majuscules-em-strong) is against it.

> On ne peut que déplorer que l’usage des accents sur les majuscules
>   soit flottant. On observe dans les textes manuscrits une tendance
>   certaine à l’omission des accents. En typographie, parfois, certains
>   suppriment tous les accents sur les capitales sous prétexte de
>   modernisme, en fait pour réduire les frais de composition.
>
> Il convient cependant d’observer qu’en français, l’accent a pleine
>   valeur orthographique. Son absence ralentit la lecture, fait hésiter
>   sur la prononciation, et peut même induire en erreur. Il en va de même
>   pour le tréma et la cédille.
>
> On veille donc, en bonne typographie, à utiliser systématiquement les
>   capitales accentuées, y compris la préposition À, comme le font bien
>   sûr tous les dictionnaires, à commencer par le Dictionnaire de
>   l’Académie française, ou les grammaires, comme Le Bon Usage de
>   Grevisse, mais aussi l’Imprimerie nationale, la Bibliothèque de la
>   Pléiade, etc. Quant aux textes manuscrits ou dactylographiés, il est
>   évident que leurs auteurs, dans un souci de clarté et de correction,
>   auraient tout intérêt à suivre également cette règle.

See also

[Accentuation des majuscules — Accents on upper-case letters](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/60/accentuation-des-majuscules-accents-on-upper-case-letters)

and references therein. Also, among many excellent sources in Internet:

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_des_majuscules_en_fran%C3%A7ais

https://www.druide.com/fr/enquetes/faut-il-accentuer-les-majuscules-et-les-capitales

https://www.question-orthographe.fr/question/majuscule-et-accent/

https://neoplume.fr/doit-on-mettre-un-accent-sur-les-majuscules/

Regarding Google error (quoting @Luke Sawczak)

*Almost certainly a technical issue. Even when the overall program is in one language, it still tries to detect the language at a word and sentence level, and that technology still seems to be iffy. Similarly, I just had a case where Word correctly detected that a whole document was in French... except for the single word "décembre", which it was sure was supposed to be "December"*

Comment: Then why does Google Docs think that is a word? I made sure my Google Docs language is French.

Comment: @kyleplo No natif speaker but as far as I know there is no etude. I don't have an explanation for Google Docs. See also http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/etude

Comment: There is no etude in French. And even if a lot of people think Google always knows everything, it is still imperfect. You can't rely on him :)

Comment: @kyleplo To elaborate more on Carneline excellent comment, you should check a word in question in a online dictionary and even better acquire a hard copy of a trusted dictionary.

Comment: Si la page de code 437 de la table ASCII étendue IBM de 1981 contient les caractères À et É, il doit y avoir une raison ! Mais pour les cuistres de tout poil, « les majuscules ne s'accentuent pas », je crains que leur bêtise n'ait atteint un stade aigu, c'est grave.

Comment: @kyleplo Almost certainly a technical issue. Even when the overall program is in one language, it still tries to detect the language at a word and sentence level, and that technology still seems to be iffy. Similarly, I just had a case where Word correctly detected that a whole document was in French... except for the single word "décembre", which it was sure was supposed to be "December". ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯